# Operador "?" em PHP, para que serve?

Tags: php

Estou estudando php, peguei um código para mexer e não estou achando referencia para o sinal de interrogação no php, que serve no exemplo abaixo, para o que serve.

```
$dinheiro = $debito <= 1 ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

Comment: É o operador ternário, dá uma olhada no link que o rray postou que tem ótimas respostas.

Answer (score 4):

Chama-se Operador Ternário.

Isso significa: se o valor de $debito for menor ou igual a um, a variável $dinheiro fica com o valor de FALSE, senão fica com o valor de True.

Isto pode ser comparado com:

```
if($debito<=1)
{
   $dinheiro = false;
}
else
{
   $dinheiro = true;
}
```